# Get objects from json web service in background ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am developing an app where almost everything are `collectionViews` with `images`.

When the app starts you can see a `TimeLine` with pictures, each `cell` has an userName who uploaded the picture, city of the picture, and the picture.

Well, if you `tap` the city name `Label` (in the timeline `cell`) you can see the city profile with all the images of that city(in a `collection view`), score of the city and some details. If I `tap` at any picture, a new photogallery `ViewController` is launched and as I have the `NSArray` of all the pictures I can do `scroll` an see all the pictures of the city.

When I `tap` the username `label`(in the timeline `cell`) the same `happens`, I download user information and the `array` of user pictures and display at the user profile.

Well, the problem comes when I press one picture of the timeLine `cell`, that picture launch the PhotoGallery `ViewController` directly (without launch the city or user profile where I download the array of pictures), so I only have an NSArray with one picture.

So, my question is

**How can I get the user images `array` in background while I am displaying the picture? **

I have thought I can call a class method in `User class` called `getUserPictureArray` and there make a call to the server, get those images and return them with a `delegate`. But I do not why I think that is not the best way.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at AFNetworking  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Comment: I'm confused. You clearly know how to retrieve media from your server. Why aren't you just doing that when you push your gallery? Also, the title of your question mentions background fetching. Therefore, I'll take the opportunity to recommend Grand Central Dispatch (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) if you're not already using it.

Comment: I currently use AFNetworking, so I already know it. I just wanted to display that picture while I am downloading all the user images) What I want to do is get this data without lock the main thread.. There are users with a big amount of pictures

Answer (score 0):

So as guys in comments says... Use [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) and [GCD](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) in your `getUserPictureArray` method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Do whatever you want with data in responseObject
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Handle error
  }];
});
```

If you do something like this it will download data in background and in `success` block you can save thos photos to `NSArray` or do whatever you want with them. But remember to do it wisely and do not referenc to this `NSArray` when it's empty.

Comment: Yeah, that is the point, I can not use this NSArray until I get it, so I lock the main thread

Comment: So you have to observe and notify when `NSArray` is filled with those images.